# MySQL 5.7 Upgradation - Binary log basename

Tags: mysql, replication

Recently upgraded to `MySQL 5.7` and I am in the process of setting up `binary log.` I have enabled the binary log but I am not able to set the `log_bin_basename` and binary log path. It showing it is a **global read only variable.** I need to separate binary logs from data directory. **How to edit the `log_bin_basename`?**. After editing in configuration file, the server not starting. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this the Master?  Or a Slave?  Please show us the line(s) in my.cnf that you changed before it "not starting".

Comment: @Rick James - I have not yet started the replication in this server. It is a newly built testing server. In default, there was only log_bin commented, nothing else was there, I have been adding other variable configuration.

Comment: If you are not capturing changes to the binlog, and you are writing to the Master, then the Slave will get out of sync.

Comment: Probably `log_bin_basename` can be set only in `my.cnf`, followed by a reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After, discussion with my colleagues, I found that, the `log_bin_basename` is **read only variable** and it took the value from the `log-bin` definition. So I added another variable `log-bin`, without modifying the default `log_bin` variable. Now the binary log enabled and basename pointed to the separate directory.

```
# BINARY LOGGING
#log_bin # This is default
log-bin                       =       /logs/binlog/mysql-bin
log_bin_basename              =       /logs/binlog/mysql-bin
expire_logs_days              =       5
sync-binlog                   =       1
```